# Messages read by groups without own database table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this table used when a user writes a note.
When writing a note, the user specifies if a sell-department and/or a buy-department should receive the note.

Each user can create a Case (lets say its just a table with case_id and case_text). And the notes the users write are related to a case.

So the table NOTES is (postgres database) something like this:

```
ID
TEXT (the message itself)
USER_ID (the user that writes the note)
CASE_ID (the case_id for which the note is been written)
```

Short word about users:
There are "ordinary" users and those working on a department. This should not make big difference for the description here.

When an ordinary user writes a note, let's say he want both buy-department and sell-department to be included (being informed about the note/see the note).

What happens now is that there is another table called UserNotes. It looks like this:

```
ID
IS_READ
NOTE_ID
USER_ID
DEPARTMENT_ID
READ_AT_DATE
```

So ordinary user with id = 1 writes this note and in the code (as he tells sell and buy-departments have to be included) I search for all the users working at that specific sell-department and all those working at that specific buy-department. I then put all these users in the table UserNotes. With IS_READ false by default.

When a user in the specific sell-department reads the note, I will then change IS_READ for this user's entry in UserNotes.

This is how it works today. I don't think this is scalable. I'm already getting performance issues. I don't think it is important to know when a note has been read. So because of this I was thinking that maybe the following solution could work. Please have a look and tell me if it could be better and the current one or if you have some other suggestion please let me know:

I drop UserNotes table. I add a new filed in table Notes: READ_BY. Here I will update the field each time a user reads the note. 
I don't know if I could use some postgres-specific thing, maybe making this field a json-string and searchable.

Comment: to make a decision if your structure is optimal, most people would like to see the structure, not read a literal description. Either create one  at  http://sqlfiddle.com/ or put it in question please

Comment: I only partially agree with @VaoTsun: the **situation** is well explained but the problem is not. You are referring to two things without providing proper _quantification_. Let's start with **performance**. Is the performance issue related to the INSERT action or to the SELECT? Second, scalability: It would be fare to assume that the number of users would remain relatively stable and the only thing that would grow is the number of messages in the system, right? Last, do you have some sort of garbage disposal (e.g. delete read messages older than X days)?

Comment: Thanks @FDavidov. The problem is SELECT. A note created by an ordinary user can imply creating, let's say, 100 rows in UserNotes-table. After 100 inserted notes there could be, in theory, thousands of rows in UserNotes-table. Did you understand the approach I would like to take? Do you think it would be better than the current?

Comment: Yes, I understood your approach and no, I don't think it will solve your problem since you are not changing significantly the rate of data proliferation. I would add some timestamp to your table and retrieve all messages in the last, say, week. Being your timestamp part of a table key, will definitely help to speedup data retrieval.

Comment: But what if the note has been read 2 weeks ago b yuser X? The query will return that user X has not read the note then?